# Java Orkut Login

Tags: java, session, authentication

I want the pagesource of home page of ORKUT (http://www.ORKUT.com) in java.

But it needs to be logged in to the ORKUT before accessing any page of it. How can I do it. It should not involve browser in between

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you were *meant* to do this there would be an API. I can only think of dodgy reasons to want to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). With it you can send a POST request with your login data and then use the session ID for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind to read C# code:

```
string orkutSite = "http://www.orkut.com/Login.aspx"; // enter correct address
string formPage = "";
string afterLoginPage = "";

// Get postback data and cookies
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(orkutSite);
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
getRequest.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse form = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader response = 
        new StreamReader(form.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    formPage = response.ReadToEnd();
}

Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string,string>();
inputs.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "");
inputs.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
foreach (Match input in 
    Regex.Matches(formPage, 
        @"<input.*?name=""(?<name>.*?)"".*?(?:value=""(?<value>.*?)"".*?)? />",   
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
{
    inputs.Add(input.Groups["name"].Value, input.Groups["value"].Value);
}

inputs["username"] = "xxxxx"; // *please*, check for \\
inputs["password"] = "yyyyy"; // correct field names \\

byte[] buffer = 
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
        String.Join("&", 
            Array.ConvertAll<KeyValuePair<string, string>, string>(
                inputs.ToArray(),
                delegate(KeyValuePair item)
                {
                    return item.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value);
                })));

HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(orkutSite);
postRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
postRequest.Method = "POST";
postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// send username/password
using (Stream stream = postRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

// get response from login page
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
    postRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))

{
    afterLoginPage = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: +100 thanks for your effort for writing this code

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing that:

1) Buy Octazen that will do that for you and keep the library updated every time Orkut changes something.

2) Use watir to hijack the browser.

Doing with HTTP Client is like fixing a watch with boxing gloves under the water. It does not support JS, you have to work your way through the cookies, parsing, etc.

Comment: I don't want to involve browser.

Comment: And I think watir involves browser

Comment: I think you can hide the browser while executing. Anyways... So dive in the cookies and JS. :-)