# Download file over HTTPS using .NET (dotnet)

Tags: vb.net, file, https, download

I would like to download a file using VB.NET (preferably) or C# via HTTPS.

I have this code to download a file over plain HTTP:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim wp As WebProxy = New WebProxy("[IP number of our proxy server]", [port number of our proxy server])
wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
client.Proxy = wp
client.DownloadFile("http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png", "c:\logo.png")
```

This works.

How do I change this code to download a file that is stored on an HTTPS-server? I guess it has something to do with adding credentials or something.

Comment: Just replace `http` by `https` in the DownloadFile function.

Comment: No then I get the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." I should somehow be able to give the user name and password.

Comment: Hi... just landed here from google, didn't actually read the question, but spotted immediately a probable problem in your code: "c:\logo.png", \l is an escape sequence (invalid?) unless it has a @ before or it is "c:\\logo.png"

Comment: Hi. It's possible the proxy simply does not support proxying HTTPS traffic. Try switching the URL to https and removing the proxy bit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a certificate validator:

```
// You need to call it only once in a static constructor or multiple times there is no problem
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateCertificate;

    private static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

In VB:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ValidateCertificate
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
'...
'Your code

  Private Shared Function ValidateCertificate(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        return True
  End Function
```

Comment: IIRC you should only need to do this if the SSL certificate isn't 100% good

Comment: @Marc: Of course, I used to think that the problem was that for iar :)

Comment: @iar: Try with this:
client.DownloadFile("http://user:pass@sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png", "c:\logo.png")

Comment: @MarcosMeli: that doesn't do the trick: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request", and "The URI prefix is not recognized."

Comment: @iar the page strips the real address, try with this without spacess

client.DownloadFile("https:// user:pass@sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png")

Cheers

Comment: It gives this error message: 
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: what happend if you paste the full address in a navigator ? the file downloads ? if so the code must work, if not so the pass or user maybe is wrong

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You just need to point that address to your HTTPS resource and to inform your credential:</strike>

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadFile("https://your.resource.here", @"localfile.jog")
```

You're talking about how to log into a site protected by a HTML form login. I wrote this code sometime ago and you could to adapt it to login into your remote site: [Orkut Login Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525697/java-orkut-login/1529140#1529140)

Things you need to keep in mind:

- If that's an ASP.NET site, you need to call it first to get `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` values, as they're required to process your login postback. If it's not, skip this step.
- You need to identify that names that site uses to fill your username and password
- You must to add a `CookieContainer`. It keeps your login cookie, so subsequent calls uses that authenticated context.
- After all that, you should be able to get your remote resource and to download it

Comment: No then I get the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." I should somehow be able to give the user name and password.

Comment: ah ok, how do you login in that site? its a windows dialog, or do you have a HTML form to fill?

Comment: There is a HTML form to fill.

Comment: I don't know, it's a third party HTTPS website.

Comment: can you please check in that login page HTML source code and try to find a hidden field named `__VIEWSTATE` ?

Comment: There is no hidden field __VIEWSTATE. The only hidden fields are form_build_id and form_id.

Comment: so, isn't asp.net; take a look into my updated answer and skip first step

Comment: @Rubens Farias: Thanks for your help so far. I'm trying to figure it out using your Orkut Login Code, however I have no clue on how to convert the following piece of code from C# to VB.NET. I hope you can help me out:

    byte[] buffer = 
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
        String.Join("&", 
            Array.ConvertAll<KeyValuePair<string, string>, string>(
                inputs.ToArray(),
                delegate(KeyValuePair item)
                {
                    return item.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value);
                })));

Comment: Solve a problem at time; try to run in c# first and, later, translate to VB.NET

Comment: You are right. I'm not familiar with C#, and also rather new at VB.NET, so I decided to go with VB. Anyway, when I paste your code in C#, it's the same line of code that cannot be compiled. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2010 Beta 2. I tried to upload a screenshot but our network policy does not allow me to.

Comment: Please take a look at this screenshot, see my above message.
http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3748/codehb.png

Comment: @Rubens Farias: I am now able to login to the HTTPS-site by using your Orkut code with some modifications. At the end I'm able to retreive the HTML source of the page after the login form. On that page the link to the download is available. Now how do I go about "clicking" the link, or better: to actually download the file behind that link?

Comment: You can to use `DownloadData` or `DownloadFile` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
        creds.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic",new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));

        wc.Credentials = creds;
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;");
        //wc.Headers["Accept"] = "/";

        wc.DownloadFile(url,localpath);
```