# Download file over HTTPS using .NET (part 2)

Tags: .net, file, https, download

On a regular basis I have to do the following manually in a web browser:

1. Go to an https website.
2. Logon on a webform.
3. Click a link to download a large file (135MB).

I would like to automate this process using .NET.

Some days ago I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139277/download-file-over-https-using-net-dotnet) here. Thanks to a piece of code by Rubens Farias I am now able to perform the above steps 1 and 2. After step 2 I am able to read the HTML of the page that contains the URL to the file to be downloaded (using afterLoginPage = reader.ReadToEnd()). This page only shows up if the login is granted, so step 2 is verified to be successful.

My question is now how of course how to perform step 3. I have tried some things, but to no avail, access to the file was denied despite of the successful previous login.

To clarify things I will post the code below, of course without the actual login information and websites. At the end, variable afterLoginPage contains the HTML of the post-login page, containing the link to the file I'd like to download. This link also starts with https obviously.

```
Dim httpsSite As String = "https://www.test.test/user/login"
' enter correct address
Dim formPage As String = ""
Dim afterLoginPage As String = ""

' Get postback data and cookies
Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
Dim getRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(httpsSite), HttpWebRequest)
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
getRequest.Method = "GET"

Dim wp As WebProxy = New WebProxy("[our proxies IP address]", [our proxies port number])
wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
getRequest.Proxy = wp

Dim form As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(getRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Using response As New StreamReader(form.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
    formPage = response.ReadToEnd()
End Using

Dim inputs As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
inputs.Add("form_build_id", "[some code I'd like to keep secret]")
inputs.Add("form_id", "user_login")
For Each input As Match In Regex.Matches(formPage, "<input.*?name=""(?<name>.*?)"".*?(?:value=""(?<value>.*?)"".*?)? />", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
    If input.Groups("name").Value <> "form_build_id" And _
       input.Groups("name").Value <> "form_id" Then
        inputs.Add(input.Groups("name").Value, input.Groups("value").Value)
    End If
Next

inputs("name") = "[our login name]"
inputs("pass") = "[our login password]"

Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( _
[String].Join("&", _
Array.ConvertAll(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String), String)(inputs.ToArray(), _
Function(item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) (item.Key & "=") + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value))))

Dim postRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(httpsSite), HttpWebRequest)
postRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
postRequest.Method = "POST"
postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postRequest.Proxy = wp

' send username/password
Using stream As Stream = postRequest.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Using

' get response from login page
Using reader As New StreamReader(postRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
    afterLoginPage = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>As I said into comments in that question, you just need to use `DownloadFile` method:</strike>

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    client.DownloadFile(
        "http://www.google.com/", "google_homepage.html");
```

Just replace `"http://www.google.com/"` with your file address.

Sorry, you need to go with `HttpWebRequest`:

```
string fileAddress = "http://www.google.com/";
HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileAddress));
client.CookieContainer = cookies;
int read = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using(FileStream download = 
  new FileStream("google_homepage.html", FileMode.Create))
{
    Stream stream = client.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    while((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        download.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have converted this code to VB.NET, and am getting a protocol violation error: "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." at Dim stream As Stream = client.GetRequestStream()

Comment: You should to get ResponseStream directly; if you need to send parameters, use querystring

Comment: Never mind, I didn't convert the code correct. It works now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing the cookies along when downloading the file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain the session/authentication cookie that is sent back to you by the login form. Basically take the cookies from the response of the authentication form and send them back when you make the step 3.

This is an easy way to extend the Web Client, which should give you much simpler code than the one above:

http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html

Just:

1. Create instance of this CookieAwareWebClient
2. Post to login form
3. Download the file

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively choose to automate the Internet-Explorer instead of trying to send Web requests via HTTPS.
[Web automation with Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx) explains this using PowerShell, but you could also do this in C# when accessing Internet Explorer as a COM object.
This method works fairly well if you just need one file and do not need to be afraid of memory leaks.